# relative error of least square problem

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I'm trying to solve this problem . but I don't know how to proceed except for the fact that I can replace x with $A^TA^{-1} A^Tb$.
any help please?

Let A and Ã have full rank. Let x and $x̃$ be, respectively, the unique least-
squares solutions to the problems Ax = b and $Ãx̃ = b$, where Ã = A + E.
Then prove that

$\frac{||x~ - x ||}{||x^~}$ $\leq$ $Cond(A) \frac{||E||}{||A||}$ ($ 1 + \frac {||b||}{||A||||x^~||}$) + $Cond(A)^2 \frac{||E||}{||A||}(1+ \frac{||E||}{||A||})$

Comment: Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: @saulspatz done!